# getting correct formatting from sscanf() in c

Tags: c, scanf

I'm parsing a line to extract a string from inside a set of parens but in instances where there are multiple nested parens I don't get anything when I print procName.

e.g. 109765 ((test)) blah blah

```
sscanf(line,"%*d (%[^'('')']", procName);
```

This format is supposed to find a left-paren then return the string while ignoring any number of left and right parens, but it doesn't work in this particular case. However if there is just one set of parens it works flawlessly.

Any idea what I could be missing here? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This scanf call looks pretty messed up. Why do you think the negated character set in there is *ignoring* parentheses? And what's up with those single-quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's `"("` matches exactly 1 `'('`.
Use `"%*[(]"` to scan 1 or more `'('`.

Better to limit string input.
Breaking up format input pieces is easier to see.
Check return value.

```
char procName[100];
int cnt = sscanf(line,"%*d" " %*[(]" "%99[^()']", procName);
if (cnt == 1) OK();
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of answering the question about `sscanf` I have addressed the problem, which works no matter how many brackets there are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char input[1024];
    char funcname[33];
    char *start, *finis;
    size_t len;
    if(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) == NULL)
        return 1;

    if ((start = strrchr(input, '(' )) == NULL)    // find last '('
        return 1;
    start++;                                       // move past the bracket
    if ((finis = strchr(start, ')' )) == NULL)     // find next ')'
        return 1;

    if ((len = finis - start) >= sizeof funcname)
        return 1;

    memcpy(funcname, start, len);
    funcname [len] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", funcname);
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
109765 ((test)) blah blah
test
```